# Monitor data in and data out from of an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to know how much data (in bytes) is consumed or added to my s3 bucket. I saw metrics for the total size and number of requests but not for the amount of data over time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metrics I was looking for are BytesDownloaded and BytesUploaded which are requests metrics that I did not find since they are not collected by default.

Metrics:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html

How to enable:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/configure-request-metrics-bucket.html

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure if this is what You need:
[image: s3 bytes dashboard]

Is an example of the dashbord with max bytes in some S3 Buckets over time.
This is just an automatically created dashboard, You can have the same one for Your data if You go this way `CloudWatch -> Dashbaords -> Automatic dashboards -> S3 -> Maximize the one with BucketSizeBytes -> Define the periods`

Comment: I dont want to monitor tbe bucket size, I want it usage - bytes in and out. Get and put requests